# How to Use Powershell to execute a program against all files in a directory

Tags: powershell

I'm using windows 8 pro and want to do something I'm hoping is very simple.  I just want to execute one program against all the files of a certain type in a directory.  no trees, just in the flat directory.  In Linux I would:

```
find . -name 'exec c:\user\local\bin\myprog {} \;
```

I've literally spend a couple hours wrestling with power shell, running into policy problems, permissions, etc.  Is there some simple way I can make this happen?

Comment: did you try `get-childItem` cmdlet? It has a flag `Exec Execute Cmdlets in the given argument.` This may be useful - http://windows-powershell-scripts.blogspot.com/2009/08/unix-linux-find-equivalent-in.html

Answer (score 70):

This is easy but different than using `find` e.g.:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Foreach {c:\user\local\bin\myprog $_.fullname}
```

For doing stuff at the command line, aliases can make this a bit more terse:

```
ls -file | % {c:\user\local\bin\myprog $_.fullname}
```

PowerShell prefers commands that are narrow in focus but that can be composed together in a pipeline to provide lots of capability.  Also, PowerShell pipes .NET objects e.g. Get-ChildItem pipes System.IO.FileInfo objects.  You can then use commands like Foreach, Where, Select, Sort, Group, Format to manipulate the objects passed down the pipeline.  If you have time, I recommend you checking out my free ebook [Effective PowerShell](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=5a8d2641e0963a97&id=5A8D2641E0963A97!6929#!/view.aspx?cid=5A8D2641E0963A97&resid=5A8D2641E0963A97!6929&app=WordPdf).

Comment: thanks Keith, I got the ls -l.. command to work.  I assume I type "powershell" at the DOS prompt first, then paste the ls -file command into the dos prompt window?  Is there a more straight forward way to execute it?  also, how can I get the command executed to echo. otherwise, I can't tell what the output is from what execution.  thanks again.

Comment: Better to startup a PowerShell prompt then you don't need to type "powershell".  Commands automatically output to the console unless you redirect to a file (or $null) or capture their output in a variable.

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: Link to the ebook (valid as of 2022-04-27): https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=5A8D2641E0963A97!6929&authkey=!AJdUaNzW7L9yC18&ithint=file%2cpdf